# kafka consumer topic offset not able to apply latest issue

Tags: apache-kafka

If the program subscribing to the kafka topic is terminated and re-executed, the latest offset does not seem to be applied.
The previously called data is output again.

```
ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG = false;
ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG = 1;
ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = latest;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reset config only applies if the consumer group doesn't exist yet. If you *always* want the latest message, you'll need to call `seekToEnd()`

Comment: Thanks for forcing the offset to be up-to-date.